# How to Send "Note To Self" to an app /website I can view & edit?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, android-10, notes

On Android v10 on mobile, I use the Google "note to self".

I'd like those notes to go to an app where I can edit/delete them.

I'll settle for Google Keep, although would be ideal to send to Evernote or Any.Do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:

You can send them to Google Keep.

**Set a default list service**

1. Let your Google Assistant create and edit lists in a service, like Google Keep.
2. On your Android phone or tablet, say "**Hey Google, open Assistant settings**."
3. Under "**All settings**," tap **Notes & Lists**.
4. Tap a service to set it as your default. *Note: I tried any.do  but it new notes didn't got to it (that I could see).*
5. If you don't want to sync your notes and lists with any provider, tap Don't Sync.
   To confirm, tap Continue.
6. Any new lists created with your Google Assistant will be visible on your default list service. Any lists you created with your Google Assistant before you set a default list service won’t be available on that service.

Important: If you choose a third-party provider app as your default, that provider’s app's privacy policy applies.

[Source](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9415862)